# Ext JS xtemplate looping over nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, templates, extjs

I cannot see why the table headers in this view are not generating:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jd6Lh/

I thought you declared 'for' to change the context node so from the example provided i would expect the table headers to be output.

Can you please let me know what i am doing wrong?  Am new to Ext JS so just beginning to get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the wrong method on the Ext object (Ext.Template) -- try calling Ext.XTemplate() instead.

Comment: Yep that will be it.  Thank you!